# Conversion from basic string to vector inside for each loop

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

```
 vector<string> compactRepresent (){
    bool matched = false; 
    string dif = "";
    string currentDif = "";
    vector <string> text;

    unsigned int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < vec[0].size(); ++i)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < vec.size(); ++j) 
        {
            if (vec[0][i] != vec[j][i])
            {
                if (find(currentDif.begin(), currentDif.end(), vec[0][i]) == currentDif.end()) 
                {
                    currentDif += vec[0][i];
                }
                if (find(currentDif.begin(), currentDif.end(), vec[j][i]) == currentDif.end()) 
                {
                    currentDif += vec[j][i];
                }
                matched = true;
            }
        }
        if (matched)
        {
            dif += " {" + currentDif + "} ";
            currentDif = "";
            text.push_back(dif);
            matched = false;
        } 
        else 
        {
            dif += vec[0][i];
            currentDif = "";
            text.push_back(dif);
            matched = false;
        }
    }
    cout << dif << endl;
   return text;
}

int match (vector<string> patterns){

    vector<string> allSegment = compactRepresent();
    vector<int> matchLists;

    for(string smallPatt : patterns)
    {
        EDSM edsm(smallPatt);

        for(vector<string> segments: allSegment)
        {
            edsm.searchNextSegment(segments);
            edsm.getMatches();
        }
            matchLists = edsm.getMatches(); 
    }

    for(const int m: matchLists)
    {
    cout << m << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
 }
```

The first method *compactRepresent* represents multiple sequence in a compact way and for the second one *match*, it tries to find match using some method.

My question is when I am looping each segments thorough allsegments, it gives the data type error like follow:

```
error: conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ requested
      for(vector<string> segments: allSegment)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `for(vector<string> segments: allSegment)` be `for(string segments: allSegment)`? You are trying to enumerate a `vector<string>` as though it contains `vector<string>` elements, which makes no sense.

Comment: The error is saying you can't convert a `string` to a `vector<string>`.

Comment: that worked: but I need  _segments_ to be type of vector because, I am passing to the function ' edsm.searchNextSegments(segments)'  which takes a vector type. @cdhowie

Comment: @Shukri Then the definition of `allSegment` doesn't work. You have a conceptual problem with your data types, and that may not be something we can address without a complete description of the problem you are trying to solve with this program. You are enumerating the contents of `allSegment`, which contains strings. Are you intending to pass a one-element vector to `searchNextSegments`?

Comment: @Shukri alternatively, you may want to just pass `allSegment` to `edsm.searchNextSegment`, without a loop over it. What is the definition of `EDSM::searchNextSegment`?

Answer (score 1):

Given this variable definition:

```
vector<string> allSegment;
```

This loop makes no sense:

```
for(vector<string> segments: allSegment)
```

You are asking to enumerate over a `vector<string>` but are saying that you want to assign each element into a `vector<string>` variable.  Because each element is a `string`, the compiler assumes that you want to convert each `string` element to `vector<string>`, but there is no such implicit conversion, hence the error.

Change your loop to this:

```
for(string segments: allSegment)
```

---

Note that even this could be improved, as you are *copying* each string in the vector when enumerating the vector contents.  Consider taking a `const` reference to each string, only copying when you need to:

```
for(string const &segments: allSegment)
```